# Bring UIImageView to front while animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiimageview

How can we make an UIImageView to go over/above other subview/UIImageView while animating? Please check the white king in the picture

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations:{                    
                    self.squares[moveInfo.start.0][moveInfo.start.1].occupyingPieceImageView.frame =
                    self.squares[moveInfo.end.0][moveInfo.end.1].frame

                    }
```

[image: see the white king]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations:{
                    self.view.bringSubViewToFront(self.squares[moveInfo.start.0][moveInfo.start.1].occupyingPieceImageView)                  
                    self.squares[moveInfo.start.0][moveInfo.start.1].occupyingPieceImageView.frame =
                    self.squares[moveInfo.end.0][moveInfo.end.1].frame

                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If `piece` is your `UIImageView` that you want to be in front of its siblings, use:

```
piece.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(piece)
```

Comment: I did bring it to front when I add the ImageView to the board. But it seems before triggering the animation I need to bring it to the front again.

Comment: Probably because other items were added later, and later items always go in front of earlier ones.